# Rails CSV Download - Specify columns and get full URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm developing a marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell.

I have a download CSV method which lets sellers download their listings.

My method below downloads all columns. I have two questions:

1) How do I specify columns, let's say I only want name, image, price.

2) In the model, the image field just stores the image name such as item.jpg. But I want to export the URL where the image is stored. I'm using Paperclip to load images and Dropbox to save them. So each image has a dropbox url, which I want to export.

my method in the model:

```
def self.to_csv(listings)
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    listings.each do |listing|
    csv << listing.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I specify columns, let's say I only want name, image, price.

You need to change the `.values_at(*column_names)` part to select only the columns you want:

```
def self.to_csv(listings)
  wanted_columns = [:name, :image, :price]
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << wanted_columns
    listings.each do |listing|
      csv << listing.attributes.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*wanted_columns)
    end
  end
end
```

> 2) export the image's URL in the CSV file

You probably have a method like `image.url` which returns the URL of the image:

```
def self.to_csv(listings)
  wanted_columns = [:name, :price]
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << wanted_columns + [:image]
    listings.each do |listing|
      attrs = listing.attributes.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*wanted_columns)
      attrs.push(listing.image.url) # if image is not always present, use `listing.image.try(:url)`
      csv << attrs
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This gives me name, price and image as blank columns and a fourth column with the image url.

Comment: Thanks. Very close. Now I get all columns but I get 4 columns - name, price, image and a fourth column with the url. I don't need the image column because I have the url in the 4th column. The fourth column doesn't have a column name but I want it to be the same name "image".

Comment: @Moosa are you sure that the `wanted_columns` array contains only `:name` and `:price`?

Comment: Got it. Did you just edit it to make it `+ [:image]`. I think that did it. Thank you for the time. Super helpful.